# Convert from Relative Magnitude to Mass

Tags: mass, astrophysics, galaxies, luminosity, galaxy-rotation-curve

I have data which gives me the magnitude density (${\rm mag}\,{\rm arcsec}^{-2}$) of M31 as a function of radius.  How can I convert these data to the (enclosed) mass at a given radius (for velocity curve analysis)?
Here's a chart of the data.  The odd thing about the magnitude profile is that it looks exactly like a mass profile which leads me to believe there's a simple way to relate the two.
[image]

Comment: Isn't magnitude a measure of relative luminosity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A magnitude is a somewhat convoluted measurement of luminosity. You probably have relative magnitude $m$ per $\rm arcsec^2$.

You can start by using the distance modulus $m-M$ to calculate the absolute magnitude $M$:

$$m-M=5\left(\log_{10}\left(\frac{d}{\rm pc}\right) - 1\right)$$

where $d$ is the distance.

Once you have the absolute magnitude you can convert that to a luminosity using:

$$M-M_\odot=-2.5\log_{10}\left(\frac{L}{\rm L_\odot}\right)$$

$\rm L_\odot$ is the solar luminosity. $M_\odot$ is the absolute magnitude of the Sun (not to be confused with $\rm M_\odot$, the solar mass, notice the italic/upright characters). Note that this formula is only technically correct for the bolometric luminosity, that is integrated over all wavelengths, but if you have a sufficiently broad filter, or make some correction to your magnitude, it can still be used.

And finally a luminosity can be related to a (stellar) mass $M_*$ as:

$$\frac{L}{\rm L_\odot}=\Upsilon\frac{M_*}{\rm M_\odot}$$

The mass to light ratio $\Upsilon$ is its own art form. Crudely you can set it to $1$ (a solar mass of stars emits a solar luminosity of light, makes sense as a rough guess), but to get beyond that you'll have to dig through the literature as choosing accurate $\Upsilon$ is quite involved (you'll need, at a minimum, measurements in at least two filters).

Putting all that together you should now have converted your ${\rm mag}\,{\rm arcsec}^{-2}$ measurements to ${\rm M}_\odot\,{\rm arcsec}^{-2}$. From there you can just integrate over solid angle to get a radial mass profile.

Comment: Kyle, thanks very much.  This would work if I was trying to convert the total magnitude of a galaxy into a mass.  The problem is that I'm given a profile of a galaxy (M31) in μ / arsec² vs radius and I want to know the mass at a given radius.

Comment: @DonaldRoyAirey The same thing still applies! Use rel. mag. /arcsec^2 to get abs. mag. /arcsec^2, to get L/arcsec^2, to get M*/arcsec^2 then integrate over solid angle. You can think of it as a differential quantity if you prefer, like a ${\rm d}\Omega$. It just sits there as you manipulate $m$ into ${\rm M}_*$, then you integrate at the end.